# jQuery scroller plugin amendment

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am currently using Max Vergelli's scroller plugin (http://www.maxvergelli.com/jquery-scroller/) and it is fantastic apart from the fact I need a slight amendment to it.  However, I can't see a way to do it with the variables given.

Here is a jsFiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/X6DwY/6/

I am looking to set the text to be at the top of the #.vertical_scroller Div (so some of the text is already visible) not pre-hidden underneath it, then begins to scroll on-hover.

I think the plugin needs to be slightly altered for this to be achieved but can't get hold of the creator to ask, so I have come to S.O.

Anyone have any ideas on this?  This is a bit beyond me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line:

```
var sh = parseInt(ob.parent().height());
```

to

```
var sh = 0;
```

`sh` = starting height, I assume. And it was set to the parent's height aka the bottom. `0` starts at the top then.

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X6DwY/13/)

Comment: Yep, perfect!  Thanks so much.  Could I also be cheeky and ask if you know how to change the re-start (value?) to be outside (hidden / underneath) the Div rather than re-popping back up to the top?  As if it was the original version.

Comment: kind of hacky, but it works: http://jsfiddle.net/X6DwY/15/, i added two lines, the main one being: `top: first++ > 1 ? sh : 0`